# Repeated column in mapping for entity error in Spring-MVC project

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I connected my MySql database to my Java project (using Spring-MVC) with Entities.
When I try to run the application, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities.OrdersitemsEntity column: order_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

OrdersItems Entity:

```
    package com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ordersitems", schema = "theprocess", catalog = "")
@IdClass(OrdersitemsEntityPK.class)
public class OrdersitemsEntity {
    private String productId;
    private String orderId;
    private Integer qunatity;
    private ProductsEntity productsByProductId;
    private OrdersEntity ordersByOrderId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "qunatity")
    public Integer getQunatity() {
        return qunatity;
    }

    public void setQunatity(Integer qunatity) {
        this.qunatity = qunatity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        OrdersitemsEntity that = (OrdersitemsEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(productId, that.productId) &&
                Objects.equals(orderId, that.orderId) &&
                Objects.equals(qunatity, that.qunatity);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(productId, orderId, qunatity);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id", nullable = false)
    public ProductsEntity getProductsByProductId() {
        return productsByProductId;
    }

    public void setProductsByProductId(ProductsEntity productsByProductId) {
        this.productsByProductId = productsByProductId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "orderId", referencedColumnName = "orderId", nullable = false)
    public OrdersEntity getOrdersByOrderId() {
        return ordersByOrderId;
    }

    public void setOrdersByOrderId(OrdersEntity ordersByOrderId) {
        this.ordersByOrderId = ordersByOrderId;
    }
}
```

Orders Entity:

```
package com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", schema = "theprocess", catalog = "")
public class OrdersEntity {
    private String orderId;
    private String notesFromClient;
    private Timestamp orderDate;
    private String orderStatus;
    private String totalSum;
    private ClientsEntity clientsByClientId;
    private Collection<OrdersitemsEntity> ordersitemsByOrderId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderId")
    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "notes_from_client")
    public String getNotesFromClient() {
        return notesFromClient;
    }

    public void setNotesFromClient(String notesFromClient) {
        this.notesFromClient = notesFromClient;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "order_date")
    public Timestamp getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Timestamp orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "order_status")
    public String getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }

    public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "totalSum")
    public String getTotalSum() {
        return totalSum;
    }

    public void setTotalSum(String totalSum) {
        this.totalSum = totalSum;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        OrdersEntity that = (OrdersEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(orderId, that.orderId) &&
                Objects.equals(notesFromClient, that.notesFromClient) &&
                Objects.equals(orderDate, that.orderDate) &&
                Objects.equals(orderStatus, that.orderStatus) &&
                Objects.equals(totalSum, that.totalSum);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(orderId, notesFromClient, orderDate, orderStatus, totalSum);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "client_id", nullable = false)
    public ClientsEntity getClientsByClientId() {
        return clientsByClientId;
    }

    public void setClientsByClientId(ClientsEntity clientsByClientId) {
        this.clientsByClientId = clientsByClientId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ordersByOrderId")
    public Collection<OrdersitemsEntity> getOrdersitemsByOrderId() {
        return ordersitemsByOrderId;
    }

    public void setOrdersitemsByOrderId(Collection<OrdersitemsEntity> ordersitemsByOrderId) {
        this.ordersitemsByOrderId = ordersitemsByOrderId;
    }
}
```

OrdersItemsPK class:

```
package com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class OrdersitemsEntityPK implements Serializable {
    private String productId;
    private String orderId;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @Id
    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @Column(name = "orderId")
    @Id
    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        OrdersitemsEntityPK that = (OrdersitemsEntityPK) o;
        return Objects.equals(productId, that.productId) &&
                Objects.equals(orderId, that.orderId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(productId, orderId);
    }
}
```

Products Entity:

```
package com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "products", schema = "theprocess", catalog = "")
public class ProductsEntity {
    private String productId;
    private Integer availableInStock;
    private String brand;
    private String image;
    private Integer price;
    private String productCategoryTree;
    private String productName;
    private Integer rating;
    private Collection<OrdersitemsEntity> ordersitemsByProductId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "available_in_stock")
    public Integer getAvailableInStock() {
        return availableInStock;
    }

    public void setAvailableInStock(Integer availableInStock) {
        this.availableInStock = availableInStock;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "brand")
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "image")
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "price")
    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "product_category_tree")
    public String getProductCategoryTree() {
        return productCategoryTree;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryTree(String productCategoryTree) {
        this.productCategoryTree = productCategoryTree;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "rating")
    public Integer getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(Integer rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ProductsEntity that = (ProductsEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(productId, that.productId) &&
                Objects.equals(availableInStock, that.availableInStock) &&
                Objects.equals(brand, that.brand) &&
                Objects.equals(image, that.image) &&
                Objects.equals(price, that.price) &&
                Objects.equals(productCategoryTree, that.productCategoryTree) &&
                Objects.equals(productName, that.productName) &&
                Objects.equals(rating, that.rating);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(productId, availableInStock, brand, image, price, productCategoryTree, productName, rating);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productsByProductId")
    public Collection<OrdersitemsEntity> getOrdersitemsByProductId() {
        return ordersitemsByProductId;
    }

    public void setOrdersitemsByProductId(Collection<OrdersitemsEntity> ordersitemsByProductId) {
        this.ordersitemsByProductId = ordersitemsByProductId;
    }
}
```

Ordersitems connects between Orders and Products - it contains the products of each order, so productId and orderId both foreign keys in Orderitems.

I think I understand the error, if I'm not wrong, the reapeted column error refers to:

```
@Id
    @Column(name = "orderId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
```

and:

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "orderId", referencedColumnName = "orderId", nullable = false)
    public OrdersEntity getOrdersByOrderId() {
        return ordersByOrderId;
    }

    public void setOrdersByOrderId(OrdersEntity ordersByOrderId) {
        this.ordersByOrderId = ordersByOrderId;
    }
```

But whatever I tried to do didn't solve the problem or even added other errors.
Can you please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Why there is two @Id annotation in OrdersitemsEntityPK class?

Comment: I actually uploaded the wrong class, edited. But there are two Id annotations because this class connects between Products and Orders so both ProductId and OrderId are keys in that class

Comment: @batFlash123 could do you share your class OrdersitemsEntityPK?

Comment: @cralfaro sure, edited

Comment: @batFlash123 yeap, the problem is your annotation Id inside your PK class, remove that annotation and will works :)